# Java - Format a String to show a pound sign and a decimal with two leading zeroes using objects and the toString method?

Tags: java, formatting

I have tried

```
System.out.println(myLorry.toString(registration, myCar.calcCharge()));
```

which outputs

```
Registration: TA17 NDD Charge: 7.0
```

I want my program to output

```
Registration: TA17 NDD Charge: £7.00
```

How can I format this correctly?

EDIT:
Why doesn't formatting work correctly? It says it's expecting two parameters but can only find one. I need to call objects using the toString method.

```
System.out.printf("%s £%.2f" ,myCar.toString(registration, myCar.calcCharge()));
```

Comment: You could use `DecimalFormat`

Comment: How does decimal format work?

Comment: Did you read its docs? They're freely available, if you search for "Java DecimalFormat."

Comment: You might want to Override the toString method in the class of myLorry. You can format the string however you want it

Comment: @Nebula I have just done an answer.

Answer (score 1):

like @davidxxx suggest in comment you can use

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("'£'0.00");
System.out.println(d.format(7.0));
```

**Output**

```
£7,00
```

---

If you have a problem with `dot(.)` and `comma(,)` then you can use `DecimalFormatSymbols` :

```
DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("'£'0.00");
DecimalFormatSymbols sym = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
sym.setDecimalSeparator('.');
d.setDecimalFormatSymbols(sym);
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution is to use the [`printf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).
e.g.

```
double value = 7.0;
System.out.printf("%s%.2f","£", value);
```

output:

```
£7.00
```

Comment: Why doesn't this work correctly?
System.out.printf("%s £%.2f" myCar.toString(registration,myCar.calcCharge()));

Comment: you have used two formatting placeholders (%s %f) but only one parameter (a string)

Answer (score 0):

In fact you should consider two things :

- formatting the number value with the fixed number of digits for the floating part.
- setting the decimal separator character.

The second point may matter as according to the locale set by the JVM, you could get a distinct result :  `£7.00` or `£7,00`

So, you could specify the `"£0.00"` pattern in `DecimalFormat`  and  create the `DecimalFormat` instance with a specific `DecimalFormatSymbols` that ensures that you will use as decimal symbol the `.` character.

You could do it for example :

```
float f = 7;
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator('.');
NumberFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("£0.00", otherSymbols);
String valueFormated = formatter.format(f);
```

But in fact a more simple way would be to use the `String.format()` method by specifying both the expected pattern (two digits for the floating part) and a `Locale` that uses the `.` as decimal separator :

```
float f = 7;
String valueFormated = String.format(Locale.US, "£%.2f", f);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it! I was looking in completely the wrong part of my program, here is my solution:

```
  String toString(String rn, double calcCharge)
        {
            DecimalFormat d = new DecimalFormat("£0.00");
            return "Registration: " + rn + " Charge: " + d.format(calcCharge());
        }
```

I had to modify a class that my subclasses inherited from.